# My app is not appearing for my phone in the google play store

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I have an app with the following manifest that I can't see on my phone.  Nearly everyone else can see it but the common factor between the phones that cannot is that they don't have working sim cards or are roaming out of the country.  Is there any change I can make in the manifest to make it not need carriers or sim cards?  I am using a Samsung Galaxy S3 and my friend with the exact same version Galaxy S3 can see the app (he has a working sim card).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="internalOnly" package="com.nanopop.app" android:versionName="1.2.0.0" android:versionCode="9">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <supports-screens 
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:xlargeScreens="true" 
        android:resizeable="true" 
        android:anyDensity="true">
    </supports-screens>
    <application />
</manifest>
```

UPDATE:

So apparently having these two lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

automatically implies that you need:

```
android.hardware.location 
android.hardware.location.network
android.hardware.location.gps
```

so would adding these lines cancel that out?

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: just for additional information I can go and download the app the the Google Play Store website, I just can't see it on the Play Store app

Comment: try to change your targetsdkversion to 17

Comment: Ah already tried that and it didn't have an effect. Just updated with some new info though.

Comment: r u using gps and google services in your project?

Comment: Yes but I handle the case in which GPS is not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens when you dont have your app supporting your phone. To confirm, check your google play store console

> APK
>
> Excluded devices 0 Manage excluded devices

In your case, you will get a few excluded devices, browse them, you should find your phone there.

If you do the following in your manifest you should be able to get a `0` on excluded devices.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Edit : Just saw your update.

Also add these to your manifest, that way you are not making it **essential** to have location.gps.

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />
```

Comment: okay thanks, do any of the use permissions that I have imply the android.hardware.telephony uses-feature?  What made you think I should add that?

Comment: Well I think I may actually need it, I was just wondering what made you add it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following with adding below line in your manifest

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
         android:required="true"/>
```

Comment: Any explanation as to why this could help?

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#glEsVersion

Comment: Just FYI : I dont have it in my manifest and I have 0 excluded devices.